# Exporting a pivot table to csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

When creating a pivot table using the following code:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index=['Player', 'Pos'], values=['Min'], aggfunc='sum')
```

The csv export returns:

```
Player    Pos        Min
A         GK         450
B         CM         1
B         DM         166
C         RB         302
C         RB,CB      169
```

How would I edit the code to return the following?:

```
Player    Pos        Min
A         GK         450
B         CM, DM     167
C         RB, CB     471
```

Comment: In original data is space after comma? Like `RB,CB` or `RB, CB` ?

Answer (score 2):

Use custom lambda function for remove duplicated values after join `Pos` strings in [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
#if there is space or not space after separator ,
f = lambda x:  ', '.join(dict.fromkeys(','.join(x).replace(' ','').split(',')))

#if there is space after separator ,
#f = lambda x: ', '.join(dict.fromkeys(', '.join(x).split(', ')))
df1 = df.groupby('Player', as_index=False).agg(Pos=('Pos',f),Min=('Min','sum'))
print (df1)
  Player     Pos  Min
0      A      GK  450
1      B  CM, DM  167
2      C  RB, CB  471
```

Or:

```
df1 = df.groupby('Player', as_index=False).agg({'Pos': f, 'Min':'sum'})
```

Comment: Thanks that lambda function works great. How would I go about applying the sum function to multiple columns not just Min say, for example, from column C to G?

Comment: @JosephDarton - If need `sum` from column `C` to `G` add  it to `.agg(Pos=('Pos',f),Min=('Min','sum'),G=('C','sum'))`